# checking the user id in a tokeninfo response, with token received from the google+ sign in button's one-time code flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus

I'm using the one-time code flow with my google+ sign in button implementation, but the user_id in the response from the tokeninfo endpoint doesn't match the id_token in the object my javascript my javascript callback receives from the sign in buton.

In the sample code in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow), the the user_id in the tokeninfo object is checked against a request parameter called gplus_id, but the sample javascript doesn't send this parameter, so I have no idea if I'm checking against the right thing.

So, to be clear about the particular sections of code I'm talking about:

The one-time code is processed on the server using [this sample code](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#step_8_initialize_the_google_api_client_library_and_start_the_google_service), and it uses a request parameter called gplus_id.

[The code in this section](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#step_6_send_the_authorization_code_to_the_server) sends the one time code to the server, but as I can see, it doesn't send a gplus_id

Comment: Can you provide links to which sample code/documentation you're referencing? There have been a lot of illustrations around, and I want to make sure we're all on the same pages.

Comment: added links to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like step 6 on the example page is incomplete, and is supposed to be sending the gplus_id, but isn't.

Take a look at the connectServer function (and the function that calls it) in https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-java/blob/master/index.html for a more complete example of how to get the user's ID and pass it to the server for verification.

(And I'll try to ping the people responsible for the documentation to get it updated and consistent across the platforms in the quickstart examples. You can also track [bug 573](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=573) to see progress on them fixing the documentation.)

**NOTE**: It is worth noting, however, that sending the gplus_id is a bit redundant. You're already trusting the code sent from the client, and you're getting the ID through steps derived from the code. So while passing and checking the gplus_id is a nice sanity check, it really doesn't gain you any additional security.

Comment: It is worth noting, however, that sending the gplus_id is a bit redundant. You're already trusting the code sent from the client, and you're getting the ID through steps derived from the code. So while passing and checking the gplus_id is a nice sanity check, it really doesn't gain you any additional security.

Comment: Your point about the gplus_id check redundancy seems logically sound, could you also confirm this is the case for the "CLIENT_ID" check in the documentation https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#step_8_initialize_the_google_api_client_library_and_start_the_google_service

Comment: ... The CLIENT_ID check does not appear in the github version of the example: https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-java/blob/master/src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/Signin.java  Related discussion: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=573