# AppEngine Java Google+ Signin missing gplus_id

Tags: java, ajax, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to sign-in to G+ with java on Google AppEngine as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow)

In Step 8, the code gets gPlusId as follow

```
 String gPlusId = request.queryParams("gplus_id");
```

and this request should be coming from the ajax call in Step 6, which only sends `authResult['code']` in the request, even the authResult doesn't have a parameter `gplus_id`

how then and where from this `gplus_id` comes ?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747986/checking-the-user-id-in-a-tokeninfo-response-with-token-received-from-the-googl might be useful.. looks like you maybe shouldnt bother with that check

Answer (score 1):

Is your request getting authorized? If yest then have you checked that you turned on Google+ API for your GAE application from the below link.

https://console.developers.google.com/project/693420044823/apiui/api/plus

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while banging my head against the same wall, and chased it around the boards for a while.  I submit that the answer is that the documentation is wrong and gplus_id is simply an unnecessary check.  [This thread on Google's issue tracker has some additional detail](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=573).  You're already trusting the one-time code sent by the client, which was obtained using the user's Google ID.  Checking a user ID obtained with the code is redundant, because the code was itself obtained with the user ID.